# What is the recommendation for adding a library reference in a project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

When I need to add a reference towards a library, I've always been told to use the "add existing project" method, and referencing the project itself inside my solution.

But here in my new company, the use another method.  They have a server which holds the compiled dll's, and keep versions of them so they can reference older versions when a change is too important to refactor older apps.

While I find this system really complicated (I guess there is a lot of work if a program pointing an older version of the dll is updated and needs some changes in this dll), they seem to find it pretty convenient.

What are the best practices for this?  Linking the dll directly? Linking the project?  And why?  Any information is welcome!

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4):

I usually take a copy of the compiled dll (if the source project is not available or if I don't need the source) and put it in a folder inside my solution, and then reference that. I check it in to source control along with my project.

I am of the opinion that you should be able to check out a project and build it directly from source control without having to go hunting dlls etc.

Answer (score 3):

The `Add existing project` method is useful when you want to reference a `library project` which is develop side by side and you want to `test/use` it's `types` and `methods` and this (`Add existing project`) method will not be used to add the reference of `pre-compiled` (`dll`) files.

Read [Project Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (MSDN) article.

Answer (score 2):

You would include it as a Project when you want to simultaneously work on the library. And that would happen mostly for small(ish) libs that will be distributed with your program (bin folder).

When an assembly is (going to be) installed in the GAC, and thus has its own release cycle, it makes more sense to reference the binary only.

Several combination of the above are possible too.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Compiled dlls is mainly when the code is more or less locked (Architecture level code ) which you hardly ever changes
eg

1) communication layer(remoting/wcf)

2) Generic Gui layer  (Wizards/dialog boxes)

3) Security layer     (azman stuff)

you only need to change when your product is going to another direction say it uses to use .net remoting as communication now it will be using WCF

Using projects as reference when you are frequently changes referenced projects
also Visual studio works out nicely order of building the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Although your company's approach is probably not very common among Microsoft developers, it is used rather successfully in the Java world. In the long run it is probably better controlled than any alternative, but without a fair amount of support scripts/programs (which, for instance, update projects/solutions automatically when needed) it can easily become unmanageable. In the Java world it is directly supported by tools such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).